# Is there a way to show an app overlay when my flutter app's deep link is clicked from another app

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, flutter-deep-link

I have deep links that are meant to open my app when they are clicked from other apps, say from WhatsApp.

However, I don't want this default behavior but rather, I need them to open an overlay. So if they are say clicked in WhatsApp then the overlay should be above WhatsApp and I should have access to the user details as they are already logged into my app. I also need this to run irrespective on if the app is already running in the background or not. Kind of like how true caller does it.

Is this in any way remotely possible using flutter?

Any help or pointers to the right direction will be much appreciated.

I am aware that there are packages such as https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window that are meant to show the overlay window but integrating them with deep links has proven to be a challenge. They also seem to not work whenever the app is cleared from ram.